GFCI Outlet Blew and Sparked
I am replacing outlets in my 1960’s house to be GFCI in the kitchen. This specific outlet had line and load wires. I found the correct line and load wires and wired the 15 amp GFCI outlet. I connected them on the side, turned on the 20 amp breaker, and there was no green light on the outlet. I then pressed the test button on the GFCI and it blew and sparked. What could be the reason for this?

Was it touching the box?

It was. There was black mark on box. I tried doing it again with another outlet. Wrapped it in electrical tape and it blew/sparked again. Same screw on the hot load wire.

Please supply a picture of the breaker. I have a suspicion that these are not "line and load" wires. Likewise, the hot side of the old outlet would be informative to see - I suspect the tab connection the two receptacles is broken on it.

I added a picture of it. It’s the breaker call dishwasher. The breaker controls two outlets and the dishwasher. Fridge is plugged into one of the outlets. There is no ground to GFCI and the outlet/circuit work when I put back the old outlet (three prong)

Some of those old junction boxes are phenomenally tight for gfcis. More layers of tape (and be sure not to abrade the tape as you push in) or replace the boxes. If you do replace the boxes, this might be an excuse to buy an oscillating multitool.

It looks like the screw on that GFCI made contact with a ground wire or the side of the junction box, if metal, and shorted out when you hit the test/reset button.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? It is a small metal junction box and I did get a slim GFCI. Would wrapping the screws/wires connection in electrical tape prevent that from happening?

Slim only means depth, not width.

@DIYnoob wrap the GFCI with electrical tape around the perimeter. Several wraps should do.
